# To check if the user is logged in or not in Android SQLite

Tags: android, authentication, android-sqlite

I am new to android. I am creating a login and sign up page and save the user details in SQLite. So far I have managed to create the Login and Sign up pages and save the user details. But everytime the user starts the app the Login page pops up, I would like to direct the user to the Homepage if hes already logged in. How do i check if the user is logged in, and if yes direct him to the homepage so that he does not have to login again.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /*Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomePageActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();*/
    DatabaseUserDetails dbuserdeatils = new DatabaseUserDetails(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, dbuserdeatils.getSinlgeEntry() ? HomePageActivity.class : LoginActivity.class ));
    finish();
}
}
```

HomePageActivity:

```
public class HomePageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.updateStatus:
            //Take the user to update status activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,UpdateStatusActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.logoutUser:
            //Logout the user
            // SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("Reg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            //  editor.commit();
            finish();
            // session.isUserLoggedIn()== false;
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
            break;

    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }

}
```

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText mUsername;
EditText mPassword;
Button mLogin;
Button mSignUp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("Login");
    mUsername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    mPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    mLogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
    mSignUp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);

    mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String struserName = mUsername.getText().toString();
            String strpassword = mPassword.getText().toString();
            Log.d("onclick",strpassword);
            DatabaseUserDetails dbuserdeatils = new DatabaseUserDetails(getApplicationContext(),null,null,1);
            String storedPassword = dbuserdeatils.getSinlgeEntry(struserName);
            Log.d("onclick",storedPassword);
            if(strpassword.equals(storedPassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Welcome home  "+struserName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //Go to homepage
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomePageActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Username and password do not match",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        }
    });

    mSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

                //Go to Sign up page
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
```

DatabaseUserDetails:

```
public class DatabaseUserDetails extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userDetailsDB.db";

private static final String TABLE = "userdeatils";

public static final String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "emailid";
public  SQLiteDatabase db;

public DatabaseUserDetails(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE_CLASS = "CREATE TABLE  " + TABLE + "(" +
            COLUMN_USERNAME + " " + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_PASSWORD + " " + " TEXT," +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT)";
    Log.d("onCreate",CREATE_TABLE_CLASS);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CLASS);
}

public void insertEntry(String username,String password,String emailid )
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, username);
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD,password);
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, emailid);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE,null,values);
    Log.d("insertEntry",username);
    Log.d("insertEntry",password);
    Log.d("insertEntry",emailid);

    db.close();
}
public String getSinlgeEntry(String userName)
{   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

     Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE,  new String[] {COLUMN_USERNAME,        COLUMN_PASSWORD}, COLUMN_USERNAME + " = ? " , new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);
   /*  Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE, null, COLUMN_USERNAME + " =?", new String[]{userName}, null, null, null);*/
            if(cursor.getCount()<1) // UserName Not Exist
     {
        cursor.close();
        return "NOT EXIST";
    }
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String password= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSWORD));
    Log.d("getSingleEntry",password);
    cursor.close();
    return password;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

Comment: http://android-emotions.com/create-a-login-and-registration-form-in-android-using-sqlite-database/

Comment: @AdityaVyas hey the link u gave does the same thing as i have. But it does not show how to direct the user directly to the homepage if he has logged in previously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check using boolean,

```
public class SessionManager {
    // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();

    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;

    Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHiveLogin";

    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN = "isLoggedIn";

    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {

        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, isLoggedIn);

        // commit changes
        editor.commit();

        Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
    }

    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGEDIN, false);
    }
}
```

For more see [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Comment: glad to help you happy coding